# storing array of pixels for sprites

Tags: java

I am trying to write some code in Java for drawing sprites on a BufferedImage.

As of now I have each sprite in a single dimension array. However this is not good for my game because each sprite would only have one image for their sprite.

I would like each sprite to be animated meaning there would be more images to be stored. I have tried using two dimensional arrays for this but I keep running into the same issue with only one frame being stored.

What would be the proper way to solve this?

```
int[][] pxArry;
this.pxArry = new int[][]{
    new int [pxArry.length],
    new int [pxArry[1].length]
};
for(int i = 0; i < pxArry[0].length; i++)
    for(int i2 = 0; i2 < pxArry[1].length; i2++){
        this.pxArry[1][i2] = pxArry[1][i2];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not really understand how your code works, especially the initialisation of the `this.pxArray`, but I can see that you never use the iterator `i` of the first loop in the inner loop.

Try with this :

```
for(int i = 0; i < pxArry[0].length; i++)
{
    for(int i2 = 0; i2 < pxArry[i].length; i2++){
        this.pxArry[i][i2] = pxArry[i][i2];
    }
}
```